# Is my understanding of 'self' correct?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods, self

I'll provide a simple method and then explain how I see it, if this is incorrect, please let me know and correct me. I feel like I understand 'self' but still doubt my self.

```
  -(NSString *)giveBack {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi there!"];
    return string;
}

-(IBAction)displayIt {
    NSString *object = [self giveBack];
    [myView setText:object];
}
```

the "myView" is a UITextView object.

Now as for the 'self'..

I'm basically saying in my -displayIt method that I'm creating a NSString object called 'object' and storing within it a method that returns a string which says "Hi there". 
And this method (named 'giveBack') is performed ON the name of my class (whatever I named the project). Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not creating an object called `object` and then storing a method within it etc. You are creating a *variable* which can hold a *reference* to an object and storing within it a reference to an object obtained by calling a method.

*[Note: The following assumes you are using automatic memory management (ARC or garbage collection), no mention will be made of reference counts. If you are using manual memoery there is more to consider...]*

Adding line numbers to your sample:

```
1. -(NSString *)giveBack
   {
2.     NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi there!"];
3.     return string;
   }

4. -(IBAction)displayIt
   {
5.     NSString *object = [self giveBack];
6.     [myView setText:object];
   }
```

1. Declares `giveBack` as an *instance* method of the class, to be invoked it must be called on a particular instance.
2. The RHS (`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi there!"]`) calls a class method which creates an object of type `NSString` and returns a reference, of type `NSString *`, to that object. The LHS declares a *variable* (`string`) which can hold a reference to an NSString object. The assignment (`=`) stores the reference returned by the RHS into the variable declared by the LHS.
3. Return the value in `string` as the result of the method
4. Declare an instance method called `displayIt`
5. RHS: call an instance method (`giveBack`) on the object instance `self` - `self` is a reference to the current object instance when within an instance method (in this case `displayIt`). LHS: declare a variable, `object` of type `NSString *`. Assignment: store the reference to an `NSString` returned by the method call on the RHS into the variable declared on the LHS.
6. Call the instance method `setText:` on the object instance referenced by the variable `myView` passing it the reference to an `NSString` found in variable `object`.

Comment: This is by far the best explanation I've ever read.. 

I just got it..

By the way, I worded it badly in my original post, but I pretty much knew how everything worked from line 1-4. It's when the self came into play that I was unsure. But thank you for clearing EVERYTHING up for me..

Comment: Holy crap.. I have to tell you, after this.. it's like you opened up the flood gates and ALL the information is just flowing in and everything is now making so much, much more sense.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are generally correct.

But in below mention:

> And this method (named 'giveBack') is performed ON the name of my class (whatever I named the project)

I can't understand your meaning.

A class name is just a symbol (that is text for human readers).

Methods of an Objective-C class are indicated by `-` notation in the beginning of method declaration.

In other words, all method declarations start with `-` within @implementation CLASS_NAME ... @end block are instance method of CLASS_NAME class.

When we call another instance methods (within a instance method) we use `self` keyword. Because all Objective C method call must designate target object and, in this case, we are calling ourselves (current CLASS_NAME instance itself). So we use `self` keyword.

Sorry for my confusing words.. It's harder to explain I thought :-(

Answer (score 1):

you're storing the string returned by 'giveBack', not the method itself. the method is part of the class. 'self' is the instance of the object that you're calling 'giveBack' (and 'displayIt' for that matter) on.

Comment: I'm aware that I'm not storing the actual method, that's just bad wording on my part.As for the second sentence.. 

Does that mean that the instance of the object I'm calling this method on is the class I'm currently writing this method in?

So if I were to create an Xcode project titled "HelloWorld", that would be the object I'm calling the 'gieBack' method on..